# which is to be call the distributed system

Tags: asp.net

i have a question, i have windows service which is deployed to the server whih work as adata base layer to upload data to main data base server.
Then i have windows application which is deployed to multiple machine and these all machines uploads data to using that web service to the main server.

i want to know which i should call a distributed system, my windows application which is deployed to different different machines or the web service should be called the distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either one of those can really be called distributed ▪

A distributed system is set up where you can have many copies of a program running different servers. Each one is independent, and instances can be brought up/down without bother any other existing ones. For more in depth (and probably a little more accurate) information check out this wikipedia article on [Distributed Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)

▪ Going by some definitions your windows applications *could* be called distributed, but it sounds like that is just a client, and not really doing any of the work.